# Android - uncheck a SwitchPreference when it has been toggled on?

Tags: android, switchpreference

I essentially want to do the following:

```
 switch.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                Boolean newVal = (Boolean) newValue;
                if (newVal && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext())) {
                    switch.setChecked(false);
                    displaySettingsDialog(); 
                    return true;
                }
```

`switch.setChecked(false);` does not appear to execute, and the switch will toggle on while `displaySettingsDialog()` happens. How do I get around this?

Comment: Try putting the switch outside your if statement, and use `setChecked(newVal)`.

Comment: I want to set it to false, though, and when the `newVal` is true.

Comment: If you want to set it to the opposite of `newVal`, do `setChecked(!newVal)`

Comment: That's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to `return false;` instead of `true`